# How to create a curve shape in CSS

Tags: html, css, curve

I'm trying to create a curve shape in CSS but I'm not able to do it. I've attached some examples of the kind of shapes I want to create.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Show what you have tried as a [mcve], along with any research you have done. SO is a terrible tutorial site. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10025627/1531971

Answer (score 0):

With border-radius you can make your elements have some shape/curves. The higher the border-radius the more curvature you will have. You can also give multiple values for different sides.

```
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#example2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50px 20px;
}
```

Read in more detail here:
 [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)